# 'int' convert to 'const int' with static_cast, but neither initialize nor have const behavior

Tags: c++, constants, static-cast

I'm following a tutorial and it says I can make non const variable to be const by using static cast. I tried to do it as follows but compiler gives me an error every time.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int j = 0;
static_cast<const int&>(j) = 5 ;

cout << j;
return 0;
}
```

Compiler gives me following error message.

```
hello.cpp: In function 'int main()':
hello.cpp:11:28: error: assignment of read-only location 'j'
 static_cast<const int&>(j) = 5 ;
```

Then I tried to see whether 'j' became constant. But I can assign value for that, compiler doesn't show any problem there.  May be compiler don't compile that line due to the issue in previous line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int j = 0;
static_cast<const int&>(j) = 5 ;
j = 8;

cout << j;
return 0;
}
```

I have searched a lot for a solution but didn't find any.

Comment: Can you link this tutorial? Your compiler is telling you that `j` cannot be assigned a value because it's a `const`, which is the behaviour you want; however, it's only `const` for the `static_cast`. `static_cast` doesn't just make it `const` always, so `j=8` works correctly.

Comment: Here it is. https://youtu.be/7arYbAhu0aw?t=331

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Constant vs mutable - which one is a variable?

A variable is what it is when you define it. If you write:

```
int j = 0; // j is a mutable int
```

Then `j` is a mutable `int`. This won't change. And if you write

```
const int j = 0; // j is a constant int
```

Then `j` is a `const int`. Writing

```
static_cast<const int&>(j)
```

Means "In the context of this expression, treat `j` as though it were `const`". That means that you can't change it's value, because it's const.

```
static_cast<const int&>(j) = 10; //Error: can't change the value of a const int
```

#### Where is `const` useful?

`const` is useful because it prevents errors that come from accidentally changing something. For example, I could write a function that counts spaces in a string:

```
int countSpaces(const std::string& s) {
    int count = 0; 
    for(char c : s) {
        if(c == ' ') count += 1;
    }
    return count; 
}.
```

Here, I am taking the parameter as a `const string&`. What does this achieve?

- Because `const std::string&` is a reference, I don't have to make a copy of the string (which would be expensive)
- Because `const std::string&` is const, the person who wrote `countSpaces` is promising that `countSpaces` won't change whatever string.

Answer (score 1):

`static_cast<const int&>(j)` creates a constant reference to `j`. That is a reference which can't be used to modify `j`. As such, `static_cast<const int&>(j) = 5` is invalid because it is attempting to modify `j` through that constant reference.

The creation of a constant reference to `j` doesn't make `j` itself a constant. It just behaves like a constant in the expression where the cast is used. Unless you keep the constant reference to `j` and use that from now on, you can still change the value of the original `j`.

Comment: It means I can pass the const reference to other function by using static_cast. Thank you.

Comment: @HareenLaks If you were to do that the other function would need to take a constant reference as an argument, in which case you can just pass the value without the cast and it will be implicitly converted to a constant reference.

Comment: yeah. I just checked that. But I'm wondering if it can just pass by value why we need a static_cast? Is there any especial cases where static_cast must use. Thanks.